# Basic django-rest-framework: how to get started writing a view?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am porting an old Django Piston REST API to use Django Rest Framework. I'm working in Django 1.7 (GeoDjango).

I'm really struggling to get to grips with DRF, though I have studied the tutorial and docs. It feels like a supertanker - incredibly powerful, but very hard to understand how it works!

What I want to do should be quite simple. I have Django models as follows:

```
class County(models.Model):
    id = models.CharField(max_length=3, unique=True, primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Place(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    county = models.ManyToManyField(County, related_name='places_in_county')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    location = models.PointField(null=True, blank=True)
    objects = models.GeoManager()
```

And I have an existing API call for queries like `placesnear?lat=52.5&lng=1.0&radius=10`. It is GET-only and available to anyone (no permissions needed).

From this call I need to return JSON like this:

```
[{
    'id': 3725,
    'county': {
        'id': 7,
        'name': 'Norfolk'
    },
    'name': 'Norwich'
}]
```

So I'm trying this in my views file:

```
 @api_view(['GET'])
 def places_near(request):
    renderer_classes = (JSONRenderer, )
    params = request.query_params
    point = Point(params['lat'], params['lng'])
    places = Place.objects.filter(location__dwithin=(point.location, D(km=params['radius'])))
    return Response(places)
```

And this in my urls file:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^placesnear/$', views.places_near),
]
```

But this gives me an AssertionError: `Cannot apply DjangoModelPermissions on a view that does not have .model or .queryset property.`.

This may be connected to the setting in my settings file (I'm not sure if this is correct, I want to make it so that the views are read-only but available to anyone):

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PAGINATION_CLASS': 'rest_framework.pagination.LimitOffsetPagination',
    'PAGE_SIZE': 100,
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.permissions.DjangoModelPermissionsOrAnonReadOnly'
    ]
}
```

How can I fix this error? And, is the approach in my views file even vaguely correct?

Answer (score 1):

Since your `places_near` API is clearly read only by looking at the code, it is safe to use the `AllowAny` permission. You can use that permission for this particular view by using the `permission_classes` decorator.

```
from rest_framework.permissions import AllowAny

@api_view(['GET'])
@permission_classes((AllowAny, ))
def places_near(request):
```

You can then decide separately what permissions you want to apply by default in your settings. The options are described [here](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/#api-reference).